# Is there an automated way to update an entity model with the Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, auto-update

It seems at this point all one can do is manually update it from within Visual Studio, recompile the assembly then deploy. Is that the only way? Or is there an easier, automated method of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [EDM Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) outside of Visual Studio in order to generate part or all of your model (Storage, Mapping, and/or Class).  If you are storing your model externally from your assembly, be sure you update your [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) accordingly.